# Installing pyusb on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, usb, python

I tried [this link](http://zombiebrainzjuice.fr/pyusb-install-on-ubuntu-homework/), but got the following message on shell:

`sudo apt-get install python-pip` :

```
vineet@vineet:~$ sudo pip install --upgrade pyusb
Downloading/unpacking pyusb
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyusb 
(from versions: 1.0.0a2,   1.0.0a2, 1.0.0a3, 1.0.0a3, 1.0.0b1)
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for pyusb  
Storing complete log in /home/vineet/.pip/pip.log
```

I want to use pyusb 1.0(or above,if it exists(i am a newbie)) which is written in python. Also will I need `libusb` to run `pyusb`? Please tell me how to download that too! I have tried an failed in both cases.I am using Ubuntu 13.10 so please respond accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer myself:

I found [this link](http://wiki.erazor-zone.de/wiki:projects:python:pyusb:setup:linux) wherein the whole procedure is outlined. Providing a gist here:

1. Download, extract and install `libusb` 1.0.9 from here: [libusb.org](http://www.libusb.org/)
2. Download, extract and install `pyusb`  1.0 from here : [SF pyusb project](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/pyusb/). This link also contains a link to a tutorial for `pyusb`.

Comment: Would you accept this one too :).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works on 13.10 but the method below works fine on 14.04.

```
sudo apt-get install python libusb-1.0-0-dev
git clone https://github.com/walac/pyusb
cd pyusb && sudo python setup.py install
```